# Fail to get server response

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Iam Using below code to send SMS to my clients through a Vendor

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
for (int i = 0;; i++) {
  String headerName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
  String headerValue = conn.getHeaderField(i);
  System.out.println(headerName + "===");
  System.out.println(headerValue);
  if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Now the following code is deployed in linux(SFTP) server having apache tomcat as sms.jsp page. This sms.jsp page is called through another page name trysms.asp and SMS is sent Successfully. Vendor server gives response that message is sent or failed. But when i call these sms.jsp from trysms.asp page,SMS is sent to the mobile number but i fail to get the response from the vendor server that msg is sent or failed in my browser.How to get that response as according to that response i have to maintain my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code to get response from vendor server

```
<%
    URL url = new URL("...");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line=reader.readLine(); 
    while(line!=null) 
    { 
       out.println(line); 
       line=reader.readLine(); 
    }
    %>
```

Main culprit was `System.out.println` which not was printing any line in browser. When i excluded `System.` then it printed.
using `HttpURLConnection` made the problem solved